# How to add an if condition for model relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have an id in a table based on a type.

What I would like to do is return a relationship based on the column value

```
public function to(){
    if($this->type === 0){
        return $this->hasOne("App\Model\X", "id","created_by");
    }else{
        return $this->hasOne("App\Model\Y", "id","to_id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) are intended for. The model with the varying column value can `morphTo` the related type.

> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association. For example, imagine users of your application can "comment" both posts and videos. Using polymorphic relationships, you can use a single comments table for both of these scenarios.